# Dynamically allocating a 3D-array in c

Tags: c, memory-management

I want to use dynamically allocated data, corresponding to a 3D array in a C program. After using the data, I would like to properly deallocate the data again.

My approach is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double ***arr3D_d( size_t dim1, size_t dim2, size_t dim3 ) {
    size_t  ii, jj;
    double  ***arr;

    arr     = calloc( (size_t)dim1, sizeof(double**) );

    for ( ii=0 ; ii < dim1 ; ++ii ) {
        arr[ii]  = calloc( (size_t)(dim1*dim2*dim3), sizeof(double*) );
        for ( jj=0 ; jj < dim2 ; ++jj) {
            arr[ii][jj] = calloc( (size_t)(dim2*dim3), sizeof(double) );
        }
    }
    return arr;
}


void free_arr3D_d( double ***arr, size_t dim1, size_t dim2 ) {
    size_t  ii, jj;

    for( ii=0 ; ii<dim1 ; ++ii ) {
        for ( jj=0 ; jj<dim2 ; ++jj ) {
            free( arr[ii][jj] );
        }
        free( arr[ii] );
    }
    free( arr );
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    size_t  ii, jj, kk, 
            dim1, dim2, dim3;

    double  ***arr3D;

    dim1    = 2;
    dim2    = 3;
    dim3    = 4;

    arr3D   = arr3D_d( dim1, dim2, dim3);

    for ( ii=0 ; ii<dim1 ; ++ii)
        for ( jj=0 ; jj<dim2 ; ++jj)
            for ( kk=0 ; kk<dim3 ; ++kk)
                printf( "arr3D[%ld][%ld][%ld] = %f (address: %p)\n", 
                        ii, jj, kk, arr3D[ii][jj][kk], 
                        (void*)&arr3D[ii][jj][kk] );

    free_arr3D_d( arr3D );
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -Wall` gives no errors and the code runs fine. Compiling with `gcc -g` and then testing with `valgrind` tells me that all memory is `free`'d.

So, everything seems to be fine. But, to be honest, I am not sure if I did the memory allocation part in a "good" way, as I don't understand it fully...

Any comments on my implementation are greatly appreciated.

**Update1**: I've just realized that there was an error in `***arr3D_d`. Fixing the bug, and adding some error check, it should read as follows

```
double ***arr3D_d( size_t dim1, size_t dim2, size_t dim3 ){
    size_t   ii, jj;
    double   ***arr;

    arr = calloc( (size_t)dim1, sizeof(double**) );
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "cannot allocate memory, probably because out of memory\n" );
        exit(0);
    }
    for ( ii=0 ; ii<dim1 ; ++ii ) {
        arr[ii] = calloc( (size_t)(dim2*dim3), sizeof(double*) );
        if (arr[ii] == NULL) {
            fprintf( stderr, "cannot allocate memory, probably because out of memory\n" );
            exit(0);
        }
        for ( jj=0 ; jj<dim2 ; ++jj ) {
            arr[ii][jj] = calloc( (size_t)(dim3), sizeof(double) );
            if (arr[ii][jj] == NULL) {
                fprintf( stderr, "cannot allocate memory, probably because out of memory\n" );
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). As shown in the answer there, this function can be written in 1-2 lines if changed to use 3D arrays instead of slow pointer tables.

Answer (score 2):

The array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays isn't the best representation of a 3D array.  You get better locality and faster referencing by allocating `dim1 * dim2 * dim3` elements, and then using arithmetic to access the required element.

I'd start with

```
struct array_3d {
    size_t length;
    size_t width;
    size_t depth;
    double *data;
}
```

and work from there.

Alternatively, allocate the data at the same time, using a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) at the end of the struct:

```
struct array_3d {
    size_t length;
    size_t width;
    size_t depth;
    double data[];
}
```

That can allow you to make a single allocation.

---

> ```
> arr     = calloc( (size_t)dim1, sizeof(double**) );
> ```

Why the no-op cast of `dim1`?  Why are we zeroing storage we're immediately assigning to?

I'd expect

```
arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * dim1);
```

---

You've made absolutely no attempt to clean up and return an error indication when allocation fails.  You'll discover that doing that properly is much easier when we have a linear array, rather than arrays of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to an error check, which I had indeed completely forgotten. Hmm, interesting point about the linear array, instead of using _pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays_, I had no idea that this gives me faster referencing (certainly easier to `free` and check for an error).

Comment: Thanks @chux - typo fixed

Comment: Two reason it's faster is that the single array is contiguous, so friendlier to caching and paging.  Also, chasing pointers is prone to memory stalls - the processor can't do anything while it's waiting for the pointer value to arrive from memory.  Multiplication by length and width isn't so prone to data stall.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning updated code:

**Unneeded cast**

No need to cast `dim1` to `size_t`.  It is already type `size_t`.

```
// arr = calloc( (size_t)dim1, sizeof(double**) );
arr = calloc(dim1, sizeof(double**) );
```

**Size to the object, not type**

Rather than code the type, use the refenced object.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// arr = calloc(dim1, sizeof(double**) );
arr = calloc(dim1, sizeof *arr);
// or 
arr = calloc(dim1, sizeof arr[0]);
```

**Pedantic: Size 0?**

If `dim1 == 0`, a return value of `NULL` is not certainly a problem.  You may want to allow for that.

```
arr = calloc(dim1, sizeof arr[0]);
// if (arr == NULL) {
if (arr == NULL && dim1 > 0) {
```

**Bug: Right size?**

It really looks like a size of `dim2` is needed here.

```
    // arr[ii] = calloc( (size_t)(dim2*dim3), sizeof(double*) );
    arr[ii] = calloc( dim2, sizeof(double*) );
```

**Declare objects when needed**

```
//size_t   ii, jj;
//...
//for ( ii=0 ; ii<dim1 ; ++ii ) {
for (size_t ii=0 ; ii<dim1 ; ++ii ) {
```

**Repeated code**

Rather than repeat code, consider a helper function.

```
static void* calloc_safe(size_t nmemb, size_t size) {
  // Uniformly handle zero cases here as desired. 
  if (nmemb > 0 && size > 0) {
    void *ptr = calloc(nmemb, size);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
      fprintf( stderr, "Cannot allocate memory %zu * %zu\n", nmemb, size);
      exit(0);
    }
    return ptr;
  }
  return NULL;
}

// Usage example - nice and clean.
double*** arr3D_d(size_t dim1, size_t dim2, size_t dim3) {
  double ***arr = calloc_safe(dim1, sizeof arr[0]);
  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < dim1; ++ii) {
    arr[ii] = calloc_safe(dim2, sizeof arr[ii][0]);
    for (size_t jj = 0; jj < dim2; ++jj) {
      arr[ii][jj] = calloc_safe(dim3, arr[ii][jj][0]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

**`calloc()` vs `malloc()`**

As code is going to fully populate that array, could use `malloc()`.

I like the 2 term `calloc()`-like function signature as it allows the function to detect overflow in size versus having the caller do so.

```
static void* malloc_safe(size_t nmemb, size_t size) {
  // Demonstrative alternative zero case handling used here
  if (nmemb == 0 || size == 0) {
    nmemb = size = 1;
  }

  if (nmemb > SIZE_MAX/size) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Size too big %zu * %zu\n", nmemb, size);
    exit(0);
  }
  void *ptr = malloc(nmemb * size);
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot allocate memory %zu * %zu\n", nmemb, size);
    exit(0);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

---

> to properly deallocate the data again.

**Freeing**

As `free(NULL)` is OK, consider allowing `free_arr3D_d(NULL, ...)` and other pointers that may be `NULL`.  This simplifies usage, especially in error handling.

```
void free_arr3D_d(double ***arr, size_t dim1, size_t dim2) {
  if (arr) {
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < dim1; ++ii) {
      if (arr[ii]) {
        for (size_t jj = 0; jj < dim2; ++jj) {
          free(arr[ii][jj]);
        }
        free(arr[ii]);
      }
    }
    free(arr);
  }
}
```